# Обновление текущего времени

Tags: java, время

Как можно обновлять текущее время каждую секунду?

Нужно реализовать напоминалку, принимаем текущее время и записываем в переменную, оно записывается один раз, а необходимо каждую секунду обновлять запись в переменной.

Comment: Обновлять время где? В переменной? В системных часах?

Comment: Nofate в переменной

Comment: Например, запустить задачу в [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) с интервалом в секунду.

Comment: @Nofate оформите, пожалуйста, ответ. Отличное решение потому что

Comment: а проще нет вариантов мне советовали этот способ ,но я туговат и пока не разобрался в потоках ,да и желанием не горю

Comment: или поясните пожалуйста

Comment: Вам надо в отдельном потоке или нужно просто так, линейно?

Comment: вобщем нужно реализовать напоминалку, принемаем текущее время и записываем в переменную, оно записывается один раз , а необходимо каждую секунду обновлять запись в переменной

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можете использовать таймер:

```
String s;

public static void main(String[] args) {     
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new getTimeEverySecond(), 0, 1000); // ставим на выполнение каждую секунду
}

static class getTimeEverySecond extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        s = dateFormat.format(date); // каждую секунду обновляем переменную
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно и так. Только доступ к `s` нужно все равно синхронизировать или делать ее волатильной.

Answer (score 6):

Для общего случая регулярного обновления значения переменной.

```
private volatile LocalDateTime dateTime;

void init() {
    ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    service.scheduleAtFixedRate((() -> dateTime = LocalDateTime.now()), 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

---

Для напоминалки можно сразу создать одноразовую задачу с нужной отсрочкой:

```
void init() {
    ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    int delay = 100; // таймаут в секундах до наступления уведомления
    service.schedule(this::doNotify, delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

void doNotify() {
    // тут выполняем логику уведомления
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Вот вам на Java

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(new Date());
    }
}, 0, 1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int hour, minute, second;
for (;;) {
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    if (second != 59) {
        second++;
    } else {
        second = 0;
        if (minute != 59) {
            minute++;
        } else {
            minute = 0;
            if (hour != 23) {
                hour++;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

но лучше юзать `unixtamestamp`